# $wpdb wordpress returning empty array

Tags: return, wordpress

I have a problem which I have been trying to resolve since yesterday.  I am trying to pass an SQL Query via `$wpdb` on wordpress but I keep getting an empty array when I try to echo the result.

I have tried `print_r` and `var_dump` and both are giving me empty values.  I would appreciate if someone can help as I cannot seem to get this thing sorted.

I have also tried calling the table via the db prefix with still no success.

Below is the code I have been using

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT CURRENT FROM upper_winds WHERE LVL=&level AND REGION=&region  AND VALID=&valid");
echo $results;
 ?>
```

P.S I have also tried `get_var` with the same problems.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried that query directly? (with PHPMyAdmin or something else?)

Comment: Change those ampersands to dollar signs and surround them with single quotes. Once you have that down, [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you weren't accounting for the wordpress database prefix, which could be why your results aren't showing up. You can prepend the prefix to your table name by using `$wpdb->prefix`.

I would suggest trying the following code:

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."upper_winds WHERE LVL = 'level' AND REGION = 'region' AND VALID = 'valid'");
echo $results;
```

I also just wanted to point out that it's important to use `$wpdb->prepare` to protect against SQL Injection attacks. Any time you are writing your own SQL, you need to use `$wpdb->prepare`. However when you use methods like `$wpdb->insert` or `$wpdb->update` that don't require you to write any SQL, then you do not need to use `$wpdb->prepare` because those functions take care of SQL Escaping for you. I can't provide sample code without knowing which of your values are strings and which values are integers.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks

Comment: Correct use of $wpdb->prefix instead of hard coding wp_ to SQL queries is the correct approach (especially if code will run on multiple WP installations)

Answer (score 0):

you need to prefix your table more than likely this is wp_ etc..

```
<?php
 global $wpdb;
 $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_upper_winds` 
            WHERE `LVL`='$level' 
            AND `REGION`='$region'  
            AND `VALID`='$valid'
            ");
 var_dump ($results);
 ?>
```

you are looking for strings in your columns but using the &?

Comment: Yeah I am using $ .. type probably because I have looking at this thing forever.  So when I prefix do I need to at wp before the DB name also? Just installed wp debug also and the query says unkown column :s

Comment: ok well try it as above if you are looking for strings level in LVL etc.

Comment: I now tried to add wp_dbname.tablename and I got not authorised user which is strange

Comment: hmm try the again, i corrected a couple of things since i changed it. You are using this on the wordpress database btw?

Comment: Hi david, Yep its a wordpress DB.  Looks like we are getting somewere.  Its gets results with SELECT * but not with SELECT COL .. but it will not take variable

Comment: if you're using variables, it should look like the above...are you sure there are matching results for the 3 variables you're entering?

Comment: David you are lifesaver .. looks like its under control now :) thanks

Comment: no problem. accept the ans if your happy with it. You can replace the above with a prepared statement or escape the values to make sure you're safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great advice and input.  Eventually I got it to work.

The problem was not only in the code as I had been changing my code many times to try to find the solution.  Eventually the main problem was nailed down to the table.  Within one of the columns I had data which was something like this 'EU-VFR'.  Apparently $wpdb did not pick up values with a '-'.  Luckily with your help and some debugging I realised.

Here is what I got now http://howtoflyahelicopter.com/upper-winds-and-temp/

Thanks again :)